# Windows 2012 DNS server: proper address resolution on one computer only

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

I need *www.example.com* to resolve to 192.168.0.1 on my local AD network.
Therefore I've added www.example.com Forward Lookup Zone on AD controller.

On my computer as well as on the server itself it works, I get proper, authoritative answer through nslookup.

But other computers, regardless of restarts, flushing DNS etc., keep saying:

```
Non authoritative answer:
Name: www.example.com
Address: [Public IP goes here]
```

Why the server gives non-authoritative, wrong answer on the rest of my computers?

Comment: well, what are the other computers users for their DNS server?

Comment: Each machine obtains DNS settings from DHCP. Primary DNS is set to AD controller (on which the DNS server has been setup). Anyway - I'm checking using nslookup and querying the AD controller.

Comment: Are the clients using ONLY the AD DNS server for DNS? Can you run the test with nslookup in `debug` mode from a client and post the output here?

Comment: @joeqwerty The clients use a secondary DNS. But thanks to your `debug` suggestion I now know what is the problem. It turns out that although example.com is a TLD, some Windows 7 machines keep adding .myDomain.local suffix to it when querying DNS. So what really happens is that AD controller cannot find this domain.

Comment: Still one thing bothers me. All right, domain members add the suffix. The server cannot find the _example.com.myDomain.local_. That's clear, too. But eventually the server realizes that the real query is _example.com_ and the zone for it is present. Why does the server return a result from public DNS records instead of it's own?